# Intermittent "Operation not permitted", "Unable to start the server" error while running 'safaridriver'

Tags: macos, mac, safari, http, sonoma

I'm encountering an intermittent issue, while trying to run `safaridriver` on OSX Sonoma. Here are the details of the problem:

I ran `sudo /usr/bin/safaridriver -p0 --enable` in the beginning.

After that when I run this multiple times `/usr/bin/safaridriver -p0`,  I was facing an issue where I receive an "Operation not permitted" error, but not consistently. This issue seems to occur intermittently.

I've checked the sudo logs, and I see the following error message:

```
    kernel: (Sandbox) Sandbox: com.apple.WebDriver.HTTPService(2049) deny(1) user-preference-write com.apple.WebDriver.HTTPService    
    cfprefsd: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.defaults:cfprefsd] rejecting write of key(s) MobileDeviceRemoteXPCEnabled in { com.apple.WebDriver.HTTPService, nimish, kCFPreferencesAnyHost,  
    /Users/nimish/Library/Preferences/com.apple.WebDriver.HTTPService.plist, managed: 0 } from process 2049 (com.apple.WebDriver.HTTPService) because setting these preferences requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access 
    cfprefsd: (CoreFoundation) [com.apple.defaults:cfprefsd] Couldn't open parent path due to [2: No such file or directory 
    kernel: (Sandbox) Sandbox: com.apple.WebDriver.HTTPService(2049) deny(1) network-bind local:*:7055 
    com.apple.WebDriver.HTTPService: (WebDriver) [com.apple.WebDriver:WebService] Error starting HTTP server listening on localhost:0: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation not permitted, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Error in bind() function} 
    com.apple.WebDriver.HTTPService: (WebDriver) [com.apple.WebDriver:XPCService] Client connection invalidated for some reason
```

I am getting this on macOS Sonoma.